# Keyboard map changes with TTY

Tags: keyboard, centos, tty

I'm belgian, and so the keayboard layout on my CentOS 7 is thus `be-latin1`.

I've set it up with `# loadkeys be2-latin1`. Everything up to here is fine, my chars are all corrects.

The thing is, when I switch to another TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Fx</kbd>), the keyboard layout is qwerty...

How can I set this keyboard layout to `be-latin1` too ?

Comment: Moved to Unix&Linux SE : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270136/keyboard-map-changes-with-tty